# Gimbal Proximity sdk throws error only on Lollipop devices

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, gimbal

I am working with gimbal proximity sdk. I am facing a strange error. The app is running perfectly fine on devices installed with pre-lollipop os versions. But when I try on lollipop devices I am getting an error at this line

```
contextContentConnector = ContextContentConnectorFactory.get(this);
```

Below is the LogCat message I am getting.

```
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197): java.lang.AssertionError: impossible
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:45)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:35)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at libcore.util.BasicLruCache.get(BasicLruCache.java:54)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at java.lang.Enum.getSharedConstants(Enum.java:211)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:191)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at com.qsl.faar.service.location.c.a.a(SourceFile:3)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at com.qsl.faar.service.location.e.a.e(SourceFile:93)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at com.qsl.faar.service.location.e.a.a(SourceFile:45)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at com.qsl.faar.service.location.d.<init>(SourceFile:65)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at com.qsl.faar.service.location.g.<init>(SourceFile:225)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at com.qsl.faar.service.b.a(SourceFile:188)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at com.qualcommlabs.usercontext.a.d.a.a(SourceFile:28)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at com.qualcommlabs.usercontext.ContextContentConnectorImpl.<init>(SourceFile:18)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at com.qualcommlabs.usercontext.ContextContentConnectorFactory.get(SourceFile:18)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at com.la.gimbalapp.MainActivity.didArrive(MainActivity.java:132)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at com.qrs.gimbalproximity.core.g.d.a(SourceFile:212)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at com.qrs.gimbalproximity.core.g.d$a.onReceive(SourceFile:58)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5274)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: values []
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:664)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:626)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:41)
12-02 18:55:29.302: E/AndroidRuntime(20197):    ... 26 more
```

Comment: Just an FYI, Gimbal has updated their SDK to support Android 5.0 (Lollipop). In fact, it seems to work better using that version of Android than Kit Kat.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having similar issues. I contacted Gimbal's customer support. Here is the answer I received:

> Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for your feedback. Currently Gimbal Android Proximity SDK doesn’t support Android 5.0(Lollipop). we would recommend developers to use Android 4.4.3 or 4.4.4 version to compile apps using Gimbal Android proximity SDK.
>
> Also, we are very interested to have Gimbal proximity work with Android 5.0.0 and are working to support with an SDK. We will let you know as soon as update is available.
>
> Thanks
> The Gimbal Team

Comment: Thank you :). I was going to write to them